# Polymer counting elements with certain attribute inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, polymer

I am using [Polymer](http://polymer-project.org) on a project. For a certain element, I have an array that is the input. This array contains JSON objects that have for example a `bool favorite`.

I want to display a certain message if none of the object is favorited. I know how to loop through the array inside a   [`<template>`](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/template.html) and I know how to use the [`filters`](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/expressions.html#filters), but how to efficiently do this I don't know.

Currently I have an extra object in my element that stores the number of favorited elements by looping through it, but this seems very inefficient.

```
dataChanged: function(){
    this.nrOfFavorites = 0;
    for(test in this.data){
        if(test.favorite){
            this.nrOfFavorites++;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, using this I'm having some issues that in other methods calling `this.fire('dataChanged')` is not calling the function, thus I cannot recount the number of favorite after (de)favoriting an item. What is the advised way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've observed(!), you can't set up `*Changed` handlers that are fired when a property of an object within an array is changed. Your existing `dataChanged` handler will only fired if an object is added or removed from the `data` array, not if an existing object's property changes.

I've put together a Polymer element, [`<observe-array-items>`](https://github.com/jeffposnick/observe-array-items), that makes it possible to observe changes to specific properties of items in an array. You can use that directly, or copy the logic.

Once you've gotten  your `dataChanged` handler to properly fire, you can either maintain a counter tracking the number of favorites (if keeping track of that is useful for your app) or use something like [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to see if there are any objects with `favorite` set.

Something like:

```
dataChanged: function() {
  this.atLeastOneFavorite = this.data.some(function(item) {
    return item.favorite;
  });
}
```